# Siemens S7, Omron FINS, Mitsubishi MC Protocol and Allen Bradley EntherNet Protocol

Tags: protocols, plc, siemens

I want to know how the variables or tags stored in all of these protocol and the different between them. To design a common database for storing the variables of these 4 PLC in MongoDB using node.js.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is that you get the specifications of each of the protocols, but you will not find those of Siemens S7 due Siemens never published it and those of Ethernet/IP can only be obtained if you are a member of odva.org

To start here you will find Omron FINS specs: https://www.myomron.com/downloads/1.Manuals/Networks/W227E12_FINS_Commands_Reference_Manual.pdf